# when I run Ant in cmd it is showing me error of build.xml not exist while I have build.xml file in my project folder

Tags: ant, build

I am a selenium user trying to generate xslt reports using Ant, but when I run Ant in cmd it is showing me error of build.xml not exist while I have build.xml file in my project folder.

1. I am using eclispe juno on windows 7 and and kept the build.xml file under the project.
2. I have java JDK1.7 on my machine and I have already set the environment variables(Java and ant both) as per instructions given on apache.org
3. Ant version is apache-ant-1.9.1
4. I have imported all necessary jar files (selenium + maven +saxon  + all required for xslt report through ant) in my project in eclipse.
   When I am trying to run ant through cmd it is showing me this error:-

BUILD FAILED

```
D:\Projects\Project\Selenium\Workspace\build.xml:70: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Below is my build.xml file:-

```
<project name="Plumslice" default="usage" basedir=".">


<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="ws.jars" value="D:\All jars"/>
<property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
<property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
<property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>

<!--target name="start-selenium-server">
<java jar="${ws.home}/lib/selenium-server.jar"/>
</target-->

<target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
<path id="classpath_jars">
<fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
<pathconvert pathsep=":"
property="test.classpath"
refid="classpath_jars"/>
</target>

<target name="init" depends="setClassPath">
<tstamp>
<format property="start.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa" />
</tstamp>
<condition property="ANT"
value="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant.bat"
else="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant">
<os family="windows" />
</condition>
<taskdef name="testng" classpath="${test.classpath}"
classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />

</target>

<!-- all -->
<target name="all">
</target>

<!-- clean -->
<target name="clean">
<delete dir="${test.dest}"/>
</target>


<!-- compile -->
<target name="compile" depends="init, clean" >
<delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
<fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*"/>
</delete>
<echo message="making directory..."/>
<mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>
<echo message="classpath------: ${test.classpath}"/>
<echo message="compiling..."/>

<javac
debug="true"
destdir="${test.dest}"
srcdir="${test.src}"
target="1.7"
classpath="${test.classpath}">
</javac>
<copy todir="${test.dest}">
<fileset dir="${test.src}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
</copy>
</target>


<!-- build -->
<target name="build" depends="init">
</target>

<!-- run -->
<target name="run" depends="compile">
<testng classpath = "${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename = "suite1" >
<xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="testng.xml"/>
</testng>
<!--
<testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" groups="fast">
<classfileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="example1/*.class"/>
</testng>
-->
</target>




<target name="usage">
<echo>
ant run will execute the test
</echo>
</target>


<path id="test.c">
<fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>

</path>

<target name="email" >
<java classname="com.qtpselenium.util.SendMail" classpath="${test.dest}" classpathref="test.c" />
</target>

      <target name="makexsltreports">
                <mkdir dir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output"/>

                <xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml" style="src/com/testing/xslt/testng-results.xsl"
                      out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">
                    <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/"/>
                    <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true"/>
                </xslt>
            </target>


</project>
```

Comment: Did u forget to add the .xml file..?

Comment: @NREZ - sorry, uploaded it now. Please help

Comment: It doesn't look like Ant failing to find your build file. The error message shows there is an error happened in line 70 in your build file. So, if the build file posted above is the one, could you plz mark line 70 out? Also, it shows "compile failed", so I think it's  reported by javac; and there should be more message, could you plz post them (if too long, use services like gist and post the link there).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your great help, I have resolved that error ..

It was related to the path of the jar files , I provided incorrect path to the jars.

This was line 70 : -

```
        <javac debug="true" destdir="${test.dest}" srcdir="${test.src}"
        target="1.7" classpath="${test.classpath}">
```

this is related to the path to the jars and in the top line of my file I did provided this path - D:\All jars , while all required jars was not in this folder, now I updated the jar folder and it is working fine now.